# How to read binary files compressed with LZMA natively with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compression, lzma

I have raw binary files compressed with LZMA algorithm (xz extension), and I want to read them natively with Spark.

I am testing this library: https://github.com/yongtang/hadoop-xz, and it seems that it works only for compressed text files, and I am wondering if it could also work for compressed binary files.

In my `build.gradle`, I have added this dependency:

```
implementation 'io.sensesecure:hadoop-xz:1.4'
```

Then in my code, I have:

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("myApp")
    .getOrCreate()

   spark.
     sparkContext.
     hadoopConfiguration.
     set("io.compression.codecs","io.sensesecure.hadoop.xz.XZCodec")


  val binaryDataDF = spark.
    read.
    format("binaryFile").
    option("io.compression.codecs","io.sensesecure.hadoop.xz.XZCodec").
    load("binaryRawFile.xz")
```

When, I try to process the content with `xzreadDF.select("content")`, I see that the content is not uncompressed.

However, when I test with text file, example:

```
  val textDataDF = spark.
    read.
    format("text").
    option("io.compression.codecs","io.sensesecure.hadoop.xz.XZCodec").
    load("test.txt.xz")
```

the above code works correctly and `textDataDF.select("value")` returns the uncompressed text.

The other workaround I have found, is to read the files as `PortableDataStream` with `spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles` and then add a map on the return rdd, and open each file as an instance of `XZInputStream`, then get the binary content with `IOUtils.toByteArray`. This also works, but I am wondering if it is not possible to do it natively with Spark using `hadoop.xz`.